# Ao fechar modal, limpar resultado de busca feita no banco

Tags: jquery, css

Preciso fechar e `limpar`o conteúdo de uma modal. Ao abri-la tenho um campo de busca onde realizo uma pesquisa no meu `bd`, e ao clicar no botão `enviar` fecho a mesma passando alguns parâmetros.
Mas ao chamar a modal para um nova pesquisa a pesquisa anterior ainda está lá. Tenho esse código que efetua o envio dos parâmetros e fecha a modal:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-mini" data-toggle="modal" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="mostraDados('parâmetros')"> enviar </button>
```

A função chamada é essa:

```
function mostraDados(pIdCooperante,pNome,pIdPropriedade,pVistoria,pUF,pIdMunicipio){    

    // ATRIBUINDO VALORES RETORANDOS AOS CAMPOS
    $("#ID").val(pIdCooperante); 
    $("#Cooperante").val(pNome); 
    $("#Propriedade").val(pIdPropriedade);
    $("#Vistoria").val(pVistoria);
    $("#UF").val(pUF);
    $("#Municipio").val(pIdMunicipio);  

}
```

Tinha feito alguns testes usando o comando `$('#ModalCooperante').modal('hide');` mas isso só esconde a modal e quando a chamo novamente a pesquisa anterior ainda permanece.

Comment: Tenta `$('#ModalCooperante').dialog('destroy').remove()`

Comment: Olá @Sorack, valeu pela dica, mas ainda não está funcionando.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pode definir valor vazio para eles um a um no evento, quando faz o `hide` da modal:

```
$("#ID").val(''); 
$("#Cooperante").val(''); 
$("#Propriedade").val('');
$("#Vistoria").val('');
$("#UF").val('');
$("#Municipio").val('');
```

Exemplo:

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  $('#form1 input').each(function() {
     $(this).val(''); 
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="form1">
  <input value="input1">
  <input value="input2">
  <input value="input3">
  <input value="input4">
  <input value="input5">
</form>

<button>Esconder Modal</button>
```

Parece-me que está a usar bootstrap, se for o metodo de modal default de bootstrap, para 'agarrar' o evento `hide` da modal faz:

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
  $('#form1 input').each(function() {
     $(this).val(''); 
  });
});
```